# writing corrupt data from kafka / json datasource in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

In spark batch jobs I usually have a JSON datasource written to a file and can use corrupt column features of the DataFrame reader to write the corrupt data out in a seperate location, and another reader to write the valid data both from the same job. ( The data is written as parquet )

But in Spark Structred Streaming I'm first reading the stream in via kafka as a string and then using from_json to get my DataFrame. Then from_json uses JsonToStructs which uses a FailFast mode in the parser and does not return the unparsed string to a column in the DataFrame. (see Note in Ref) Then how can I write corrupt data that doesn't match my schema and possibly invalid JSON to another location using SSS?

Finally in the batch job the same job can write both dataframes. But Spark Structured Streaming requires special handling for multiple sinks. Then in Spark 2.3.1 (my current version) we should include details about how to write both corrupt and invalid streams properly...

Ref: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-Expression-JsonToStructs.html

```
val rawKafkaDataFrame=spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", config.broker)
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", path.toString)
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", config.pass)
  .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "JKS")
  .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL")
  .option("subscribe", config.topic)
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")

  .load()

val jsonDataFrame = rawKafkaDataFrame.select(col("value").cast("string"))

// does not provide a corrupt column or way to work with corrupt
jsonDataFrame.select(from_json(col("value"), schema)).select("jsontostructs(value).*")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you convert to json from string, and if it is not be able to parse with the schema provided, it will return null. You can filter the null values and select the string. Something like this.

```
val jsonDF =  jsonDataFrame.withColumn("json", from_json(col("value"), schema))
val invalidJsonDF = jsonDF.filter(col("json").isNull).select("value")
```

Comment: I've been sidetracked.Then this does look like a correct approach, and I have to ask myself why I didn't think about it. However I did ask about writing the corrupt dataframe. Then because this requires writing both corrupt and valid dataframes, it seems like we need to use multiple sinks. Can you include the proper handling for that against spark streaming 2.3.1 ?

Comment: @discord What do you mean spark 2.4 makes this more reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to figure out the _corrupt_record equivalent for structured streaming as well. Here's what I came up with; hopefully it gets you closer to what you're looking for:

```
// add a status column to partition our output by
// optional: only keep the unparsed json if it was corrupt
// writes up to 2 subdirs: 'out.par/status=OK' and 'out.par/status=CORRUPT'
// additional status codes for validation of nested fields could be added in similar fashion

df.withColumn("struct", from_json($"value", schema))
  .withColumn("status", when($"struct".isNull, lit("CORRUPT")).otherwise(lit("OK")))
  .withColumn("value", when($"status" <=> lit("CORRUPT"), $"value"))
  .write
  .partitionBy("status")
  .parquet("out.par")
```

Comment: Heh, I just now realized that Dec. 2018 was not, in fact, last month...